# LARAVEL errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, mariadb

no puedo realizar ningún tipo de migración, acá mi código:

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('empresas_referentes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('empresa_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('nombre', 70);
        $table->string('apellido', 70);
        $table->string('telefono', 15);
        $table->string('email', 70);
        $table->string('horario_contacto', 255);
        $table->string('observaciones', 255);
        $table->boolean('activo')->default(1);
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('empresa_id')->references('id')->on('empresas'); #<--- acá el maldito error
    });
}
```

ésta es la tabla que quiero relacionar:

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('empresas', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('localidad_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('nombre', 70);
        $table->string('cuit', 13);
        $table->string('direccion', 120);
        $table->string('telefono', 15);
        $table->string('horario_contacto', 255);
        $table->string('observaciones', 255);
        $table->boolean('activo')->default(1);
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('localidad_id')->references('id')->on('localidades');
    });
}
```

por si no quedó claro, si quito el código donde marqué con un comentario, la migración se realiza con éxito, pero necesito que esta tabla este relacionada si o si, lo forcé desde `phpmyadmin` y me funciona perfecto, evidentemente algo estoy haciendo mal en el orm.

acá la imagen del error para que quede aún más claro

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

los estoy leyendo, gracias.

Comment: Perdiste tres días también por no buscar. Si aquí mismo escribes el término *Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed* en el buscador, encontrarás [varias preguntas/respuestas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=Foreign+key+constraint+is+incorrectly+formed) que explican los diferentes motivos por los que puede ocurrir este error, entre ellos lo que ocurría en tu caso.

Answer (score 2):

Mil disculpas a los que leyeron, ya encontré el error, y me parece útil dejar la respuesta acá porque realmente no encontré la documentación, perdí 3 días culpa de mi ignorania

acá el enlace, es la respuesta número 5:

> [el enlace a la solución](https://laraveles.com/foro/viewtopic.php?id=6034)

-laravelman 26/10/2016 23:30:38

Estimado, las migraciones se ejecutan en relación a su creación, por ejemplo:

Usuarios:id,nombre,pais_id
Paises:id,nombre

Para que la migración funcione de manera correcta primero debes crear la migracion Paises y luego Usuarios, de esa manera la migracion de Usuarios encuentra la clave foranea de la tabla Paises y así sucesivamente.

Atento a tus comentarios.

Saludos y un abrazo.